# Laptop restarts/freezes during any OS installation

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, freeze

I'm trying to install ubuntu/deepin on my old laptop (Year - 2009). After fixing on a series of issues laptop finally booted. But now I'm not able to install any OS on it. Ubuntu freezes or restarts as soon as Installation wizard pops up and deepin freezes or restarts at 0% installation progress.

Used HDD Regenerator and it found & fixed 244 bad sectors and also try switching HDD with a brand new one still same issue.

How can I figure what is the issue?

UPDATE

It appeared to be a ram issue so I got the ram replaced. And still having same issue. memtest86 crashes as soon as it starts and when i insert ram in the other slot laptop turns on for 1-2 secs (Doesn't reach bios and screen doesn't turn on) and shutdown after that.

Comment: What is the core temp?

Comment: @wysiwyg In my initial attempt when installing ubuntu I was greeted with CPU core overheating error. So I replaced the thermal paste on CPU. I'm no longer warned about CPU overheating. So it looks like that issue is fixed. The answer to your question I have no way to check CPU core temp. The laptop is really old even its bios doesn't show any temp info.

Also, I just tried using memtest86 and system reboots almost immediately as soon as memtest86 starts

Comment: You have a bad memory module, if there is more than one module remove and test each one independently by running memtest.

Comment: Are you able to boot from a liveCD?

Comment: @Moab unfortunately at the moment I have only one module which is borrowed from a friend.

Comment: @wysiwyg I don't have working CD-ROM. If you're implying that probably setup is corrupted or issue with the USB. I downloaded fresh ISO images checked md5 checksum and created several times bootable drive with different pen drives and same issue every time.

Comment: Its a memory issue......

Comment: @Moab The RAM module still has warranty gonna get it replaced. Also on RAM packaging its mentioned that it's "eco-friendly low voltage" could that be the issue?

Comment: @Moab Not saying you're wrong but I'm curious how you know for sure it's memory issue?

Comment: It crashes when running memtest.

Comment: @Moab updated question with more info

Comment: Could you post the results of the memtest run.

Comment: @harrymc memtest crashes as soon as it starts... so there isn't any result for me to post and neither did i find any logs file in there

Comment: Roughly there are 3 components that can go wrong : RAM, CPU, motherboard. The RAM was replaced so is maybe ok, which leaves the other two. A repair-shop could locate the bad component. But the question is whether you wish to spend this amount of money to fix a 9-year old computer. I really believe you should stop investing in it and buy yourself a new computer.

Comment: If the RAM is new and of the right type/speed, and memtest crashes at startup, I agree with Moab - you have a RAM issue. Most likely the motherboard, meaning you could buy yet another RAM stick and get the same problem. But make sure there's no CPU heat issue. You say you have no way to check temp - try speccy: www.piriform.com/speccy

Comment: @reben is it bootable or do i need to have an OS

Comment: That particular utility (Windows) isn't bootable, although you can put it on a windows-bootable media. But as i seems I doubt that CPU cooling is the main culprit here. just wanted to give you a tool if you wanted to pursue that issue. If so then you'd have to boot some windows 'thingy'.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of causing some anger,
I'm sorry to say, but all such questions on our site get the same answer :
We cannot diagnose hardware problems from far away.

You have changed the RAM, but as you give no details about the computer and
the new RAM, we don't even know if it fits your computer.
If you have run memtest while the computer was still booting and shown us
the results, we could have analyzed whether the errors came from the RAM
or from the motherboard.

You had errors with the disk and replaced it, but we don't know what exactly
were the errors before it was replaced.

You have done the "fixing on a series of issues", but what did you do?

You are currently spending money on trying to revive a 9-years old computer.
For your information,
not many computers survive to that age, and I think that yours didn't either.

You may take your computer to a professional repairman, who will have the tools
to pinpoint the problem or problems. But this is again money spent, and the
diagnosis might probably be that the repair is too costly to be justified.

So let me give you my best advice : Return to the shop every new part that
you have bought, if you can still be reimbursed.
Then invest your money in a new computer.

Believe me, your computer is not worth it, and you might find yourself
spending on it more money than the price of a new one.

And what will you have after fixing it ?
A 9-year old computer which is vastly inferior to even a cheap new computer.
Technology has much advanced in the last 9 years.

Excuse me for this rant, but I have seen too many such cases pass here.

Answer (score 2):

I would worry about running an old system unless the hardware is defective you should get it to work (for whatever reason you want it to work). Since you tried several approaches and the problem still persists you should try to minimize the problem sources. Especially if you're problem is a combination of two or more independent sources it might help you to get

- Load the default BIOS settings ("save settings" if the BIOS gives you that option) and disable as much as possible
- Remove as much (additional) hardware as possible so you just use the essentials
- Try only to use hardware you verified on a different system

If you can get it to boot into BIOS you could try to continue doing further tests or try to boot an operating system. If you can't get the BIOS to load, let us know, there's still a few things to try out, but you have to decided if it's worth the time/money afford since there is no guarantee that you will get it to work (e.g. if there's s.th. defective on the mainboard which you can't replace easily).